# mysql optimize table crash

Tags: mysql, myisam, optimization

When I try `` OPTIMIZE TABLE  `table` `` (MyISAM) on a table which is about 300MB, then it is crashed and must be repaired. What could cause this problem? The same problem occurs on other tables over 300MB.

Comment: Did you try repairing the tables and retrying the `OPTIMIZE`?

Comment: please provide MySQL server version, also show your `my.cnf` without comments (on Linux it would be `/etc/my.cnf`).

Comment: Yes, after repair, optimize works. But next day, it crashs again.

Comment: can you provide your server config (pysical server like memory/disk), does the mysql error log display any message?

Answer (score 2):

MYISAM tables are very fragile and get damaged/crash every now and then. First advice is to move to Innodb engine it is simply performed by using alter table command.

Now, to fix crashed MYISAM tables the proper way is to bring the MYSQL down and once it is down and there is no traffic you can fix them using this command line statement:

```
myisamchk --silent --force --fast  /path/table-name.MYI
```

Trying to repair/optimise MYISAM tables on a live server usually does not work. From MYSQL CLI the command should be

```
mysql> repair table tablename;
```

instead of `optimize table` if the table was crashed.

Comment: Table crashes after `optimize table`. InnoDB would be better, but this is table for fulltext search.